# UIAlertView with RSS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I want to make a application that when the app open, a alertview pop up with the RSS news with one or most posts. Is there any example or tutorial about it?

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you don't open an AlertView when your app launches. This is a poor user experience. That being said all you need to do is launch an alertView with the message set to a string pulled from an RSS feed.

Comment: You may need to split this into two questions: How do I use UIAlertView? and How do I download RSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters you just need to create the UIAlertView and display it. You'll have to implement a delegate if you want to know when they tap OK. Just fill the NSString with whatever you want to display.

```
[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"News" message:rssString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
```

I'm assuming you need to know how to download RSS as well. This is not the best way but it is the easiest to download rss into a string.

```
NSString *rssOutput = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://news.google.com/?output=rss"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

// No rss returned
if (!rssOutput) {
    NSLog(@"No Data");
}
```

After you're going to need to parse it to find the post you want. There are several parsers available including Apple's own NSXMLParser built into Mac and iOS. I think explaining that here is beyond the scope of the post so I'd look at Apple's own documentation to better understand how to use it.

Here is a useful walkthrough as well. http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3018